# How to do a HTTP Post in Android?

Tags: android, http, http-post

i am new to android app development, what i need is i have two textbox username and password,it will post to server and check it with the DB using a php page, if the login success then go to next screen else show a msg box showing login error how can i do that?

```java
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://google.com");
    EditText tw =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        tw.setText(status);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        tw.setText(e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        tw.setText(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending POST data in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use this class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HttpLogin extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Button login;
    private EditText username, password;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String   mUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String  mPassword = password.getText().toString();

                tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword)
    {           
        HttpURLConnection connection;
       OutputStreamWriter request = null;

            URL url = null;   
            String response = null;         
            String parameters = "username="+mUsername+"&password="+mPassword;   

            try
            {
                url = new URL("your login URL");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                request.write(parameters);
                request.flush();
                request.close();            
                String line = "";               
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.                
                response = sb.toString();
                // You can perform UI operations here
                Toast.makeText(this,"Message from Server: \n"+ response, 0).show();             
                isr.close();
                reader.close();

            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                // Error
            }
    }
}
```

main.xml will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
<EditText android:hint="Username" android:id="@+id/username" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
<EditText android:hint="Password" android:id="@+id/password" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPassword"></EditText>
<Button android:text="Sign In" android:id="@+id/login" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but how will i get value from the textbox and so on? how can i do the new screen show??

Comment: String parameters = "username="+txtUserName.getText().toString()+"&password"=txtPassword.getText().toString();                            Here txtUserName and txtPassword are the EditText fields

Comment: thks vikas...where will i get the response?? and where should i place a screen changing code??

Comment: I have edited my answer, now you might get exactly what you want.

Comment: and while i try to load google through the web browser of emulator it showing no internet connenction...how to configure it?

Comment: Check internet connectivity on your device/ emulator or make sure the url you are using is correct.

Comment: How can i check that?? i go to browser in emulator and it showing no internet connect, am i need to configure anything in the eclipse so that i will get the net??i gave permission also..

Comment: There might be an issue with your internet connection, it is not problem of code. Make sure the option "Data Enabled" should be checked in the "Settings>>Wireless & Networks>> Mobile Networks" menu

Comment: at where in the emulator?i am using BSNL Broadband

Comment: Click on Menu the "Settings>>Wireless & Networks>> Mobile Networks>>Data enabled"

Comment: If Internet is working fine in your PC then it should run in emulator without any problem. Give up a try with creating new device and run.

Comment: Alex if you can join chat room then plz come in Android section I will be here, we can discuss in detail..

Comment: Sending passwords in plain text over the network is a very bad idea.

Comment: how can we secure it??using ssl is fully secure?? how https can be used in above code? what all to be added?

Comment: @ Octavian Damiean:  Off course it's a bad idea. But remember it's not a primary intention of this question, simply it is showing how to do a http post.

Comment: This would fail when username/password contains characters like `&` or `=`. You'd need to percentile encode the parameters.

Comment: You don't want to do this in the same thread as the user interface!

Comment: I get a `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol on URL` error.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient to make POST requests. See an example [here](http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-use-http-connection-saxparser.html).

Comment: Are you sure Internet connection is OK? Are you perhaps behind a proxy?

Comment: i dont undersstand what u mean by that?