# how to post data to remote server in android app

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do a HTTP Post in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470936/how-to-do-a-http-post-in-android)

I want to send the two values to a server ,say http://localhost/twoVal.php, which will further process the  information.

for example,

i have got the val1 = 12 and val2 = 13
i want to post these data to above mentioned URL.  (May be some URL need not be localhost) how to do it?
Also, data  needs to be sent as part of HTTP header (POST) & not as query parameters.

Comment: A simple search would do wonders.

Answer (score 9):

Have you even tried to search for the answer?

- [Http Post in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874227/android-project-using-httpclient-http-client-apache-post-get-method)
- [Android, sending XML via HTTP POST (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559948/android-sending-xml-via-http-post-soap)
- [Http post in Java](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=44)
- [Http post in Java with UrlConnection](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html)
- [HttpClient android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)