# Android to PHP and Back

Tags: php, android

Can someone provide an example of android code to send simple data to PHP server? I need to just send several string, double, and int variables from a form that was created on android device, convert those entries into a pdf document, then send that back to android. If I could just get a sample of at least sending it to server that would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a HTTP Post in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470936/how-to-do-a-http-post-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```