# Android Send and Receive data to/from php

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to send data to a php file and getting the response to my android activity.

I'm using this to send the parameters to php and to receive from it:

```
    String name = "snake", price = "10", description = "nada nada nada";

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.122/example/example.php");

    // This is the data to send

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        // This is the response from a php application
        String reverseString = response;
        Toast.makeText(this, "response" + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "CPE response " + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "IOE response " + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

and my php file its like this:

```
<?php

//code to reverse the string

$reversed = strrev($_POST["action"]);

echo $reversed;

?>
```

I think the problem is when I'm trying to receive the data from the php file. Because when I use the debug mode when it gets to `String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);` is when I get the exception.

LogCat:

```
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.login/com.example.plataformavideos.GraficosLinhas}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at com.example.plataformavideos.GraficosLinhas.postData(GraficosLinhas.java:91)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at com.example.plataformavideos.GraficosLinhas.onCreate(GraficosLinhas.java:70)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-20 10:19:39.173: E/AndroidRuntime(3580):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: This is really a duplicate of a number of things.  Try starting here: [How to do a HTTP Post in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470936/how-to-do-a-http-post-in-android)

Comment: what exception you get

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: I've searched but maybe I didn't search that well. I'll try the first link, the second one didn't worked with me. And the exception is exception since it doesn't specify what exception it is.

Comment: post your logcat with exception

Comment: I´ve posted my logcat

Comment: Read it for handling `NetworkOnMainThreadException` : [Asynktask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Check That Your Device could connect to local network or Not

**`NetworkOnMainThreadException`**

The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Prefer to Use **`AsynkTask`** to do **network operations**...

**EDIT**

You need To Do Some Changes With Your Code.......
Put Your Code In **`ASYNKTASK`**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Change this

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

this

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
```

And You Are Passing  Variables to your PHP Server (name,price,description) make sure that you have that 3 variable in your **PHP CODE FILE**

Comment: What is `sb` and `result` ? I assume `Strings`?

Comment: And how can I do with the AsynkTask ?

Comment: Now I got an error `HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);`

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Comment: The thing is my program already connects to a localhost database to get information, never to send and get

Comment: I followed this tutorial `http://adilmukarram.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/sending-and-receiving-data-from-a-php-web-application/` and I don't why its not working. With your example where should I place it in my code ?

Comment: have you defined internet permission?

Comment: By using `BasicResponseHandler` you dont need my code.. you have other problem with your code..

Comment: Change it, but I keep getting this `NetworkOnMainThreadException` even on a new app that I've created 5 min ago to test the example, everything is like the example and it gives me this exception

Comment: But I can't find a tutorial to do so :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55980/discussion-between-snakesheet-and-prags).